# Can't find Yura [Nagakiba katana quest]

Tags: elden-ring

I am trying to acquire the Nagakiba but can't find Yura or the blade anywhere.

From the [fextralife wiki](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Bloody+Finger+Hunter+Yura):

> If the player doesn't complete Yura's quest prior to being possessed
> by Shabriri, they can still acquire all items. Bloody Finger Eleonora
> will still invade at the Second Church of Marika. Killing Eleonora
> will still reward Purifying Crystal Tear, Eleonora's Poleblade, and
> one Furcalling Finger Remedy. The Nagakiba can be found at the last
> location the player spoke with Yura prior to being possessed, at
> Yura's camp north-east of the Seaside Ruins grace, or at the underpass
> below the Murkwater Coast Site of Grace (If they did not speak to Yura
> at all before meeting Shabriri.

I just went to the Second Church of Marika, got invaded and killed Eleonora. Also I remember being invaded by Bloody Finger Nerijus near Murkwater cave (and killing him) but I dont remember talking to Yura *ever*.

I checked both her locations in Limgrave and she's not there (or the blade). I tried to find the invasion sign in Raya Lucaria and can't find it. I went to Zamor Ruins' grace and Shabiri is there but no Yura around...

Anywhere else I should check ?

Answer (score 2):

I eventually found the Katana on the bridge North of Raya Lucaria's *Main Gate* grace.

Actually there was a NPC icon for Yura on the map there.

[image]

Yura wasn't there of course, but the Katana was.

[image]

So it seems if you **never** talk to Yura and go straight to Shabriri, this is the place where the Katana ends up. You just have to walk past the blue seal on the bridge a bit to the north-east and there it is.

Comment: Are you sure you never talked to Yura ? The NPC icon has been added with the update yesterday, and shows the places where you've talked with NPCs last.

Comment: @UnownK I'm 99% sure, at least I don't remember talking to Yura.

Answer (score 1):

Yura's not woman, he's a man!

If Shabriri is at Zamor Ruins' grace, Yura won't appear anywhere, since Shabriri is using his body (in other word, Yura's dead at that point.) You may have to kill Shabriri or get Frenzied Flame to disappear Shabriri (see [Fextralife](https://eldenring.wiki.fextralife.com/Shabriri) for more information, section **SHABRIRI QUESTLINE**).

Once you've killed Shabriri or you've got Frenzied Flame, the Nagakiba should be found at Yura's camp north-east of the Seaside Ruins grace, or at the underpass below the Murkwater Coast Site of Grace.